# Q: Adding dismiss button without @Binding to Launch Screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on an app where the Welcome Screen should be dismissed with a button but I can't figure out how to toggle the welcome screen. I tried to use `@Binding`  and `@AppStorage`  but no success within the existing `UserDefaults`.

Like an onboarding, the launch screen should only show screen once when the app is first opened.

Thanks for the help!

```
extension UserDefaults {
    var welcomeScreenShown: Bool {
        get {
        return (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "welcomeScreenShown") as? Bool) ?? false
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "welcomeScreenShown")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
                
    var body: some View {
        if UserDefaults.standard.welcomeScreenShown {
            HomeView()
        } else  {
            
            WelcomeScreen()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
struct WelcomeScreen: View {
    @AppStorage("welcomeScreenShown")
    var welcomeScreenShown: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Welcome to")
                        .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .bold))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .offset(y: -7)
                                        
                    Text("App")
                        .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .heavy))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .offset(y: -14)

                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Text("Get Started")
                    })
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25))
                
                    
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.white)
                .onAppear(perform: { UserDefaults.standard.welcomeScreenShown = true

                })
            }
        }
  

struct WelcomeScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WelcomeScreen()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@AppStorage` at the top level and then pass it with a `@Binding` to the `WelcomeScreen`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("welcomeScreenShown")
    var welcomeScreenShown: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if welcomeScreenShown {
            HomeView()
        } else  {
            WelcomeScreen(welcomeScreenShown: $welcomeScreenShown)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Home")
    }
}

struct WelcomeScreen: View {
    @Binding var welcomeScreenShown : Bool
 
    var body: some View {
        Text("Welcome")
        Button(action: {
            welcomeScreenShown = true
        }) {
            Text("Done")
        }
    }
}

struct WelcomeScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WelcomeScreen(welcomeScreenShown: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

Another option is to use `@AppStorage` on *both* screens, but it seems redundant.

With `@AppStroage`, there doesn't seem to be a need for your first extension.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, it worked like a charm. BIG Thank you! ♥️